# Python and Cryptography: md5

Tags: python, encryption, cryptography

I am very interested in python and cryptography and I would like to know what would be the most simple method in python to crack a hash.

I would like to build a small python script that can crack this hash:21232f297a57a5a743894a0e4a801fc3
which is simply 'admin'.

What process would I need to go through to guess what this hash represents?

I have read up about md5 and at this point in time I have only just started learning the methods behind cryptography, but they also go into deep computer science which is something I don't understand as of yet.

I did some research here: http://nsfsecurity.pr.erau.edu/crypto/md5.html

Comment: Why python specifically?

Comment: If I am not moistaken, md5 can be cracked only by a brute force attack or a dictionary. Basically download a dictionary of words and for every word do md5(word) and compare with your hash. It is not guaranteed that if it matches it will be 'admin' though.

Comment: Most of the algorithms are one way only, which is why they are the guaranty of some kind of security. That being say, MD5 is reversible, AFAIK... Keep looking.

Comment: @Golgauth MD5 is most definitely not "reversible". It is a hash, and hashes are not reversible. However, MD5 is "broken", meaning that it is possible to generate *collisions* in less-than-bruteforce time.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart That makes sense. I only said that because I already used an OpenLDAP very basic browser that was able to show the MD5 encoded passwords as clear... Even if cracking was not the purpose of the soft at all... But thanks for your precious precision.

Comment: @Golgauth <pedantic>They are MD5 *hashed*, not *encoded*. Encoding implies the decoding is possible.</pedantic> Do you have more information on this browser that can show passwords in the clear? I have a suspicion that it was not working in the exact way you describe. It's still computationally intensive to do what you describe.

Comment: @user2351394 Have a look at [John the Ripper](http://www.openwall.com/john/).

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Found it back : [LDAPExplorerTool](http://ldaptool.sourceforge.net/). But may be the passwords where not hashed as you suggested... It's a long time ago.

Answer (score 6):

You can output a hex md5 like so:

```
>>> from hashlib import md5
>>> md5('admin').hexdigest()
'21232f297a57a5a743894a0e4a801fc3'
```

If you have a list of words, you could try them one by one and output if their md5 matches your desired one. (This is known as a dictionary attack)

```
>>> words = 'test', 'alex', 'steve', 'admin'
>>> for word in words:
...     if md5(word).hexdigest() == '21232f297a57a5a743894a0e4a801fc3':
...         print word
...         break
... 
admin
```

If you were serious about cracking an MD5 you'd have much better results on the GPU - try a tool like [OCLHashCat](http://hashcat.net/oclhashcat-plus/)

Comment: He kind of asked the reversed question.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart You guys are fast to downvote. See my updated answer

Comment: @AlexL Or you are too fast to submit. -1 removed.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.google.com/search?q=md5+lookup

```
>>> import requests
>>> import lxml.html
>>> 
>>> def reverse_md5(digest):
...     r = requests.get('http://www.md5-lookup.com/index.php?q={}'.format(digest))
...     root = lxml.html.fromstring(r.content)
...     for x in root.cssselect('#LSResult table tr')[4:-3]:
...         return x.find('td').text_content() 
...     # fallback to brute force.
...     # ...
... 
>>> reverse_md5('21232f297a57a5a743894a0e4a801fc3')
'admin'
>>> reverse_md5('21232f297a57a5a743894a0e4a801fc4') # lookup fail
>>>
```

Comment: +1 nice to link to md5-lookup.com . Why the last code line though? Seems like copy/paste error to me.

Comment: @owlstead Could be to demonstrate that nothing is returned if the md5-lookup request fails?

Comment: @AlexL no need for guessing, I'll wait for the answer of falsetru (removing a single hex digit from an MD-5 string does not make much sense anyway)

Comment: @owlstead, AlexL is right. I removed a digit to make a lookup fail.

Comment: @falsetru OK, the lookup will fail, but as this is both an illegal hex string *and* an illegal MD5 value, it does not make too much sense; replacing one or two hex digits with different ones makes more sense. MD5 values need to be 16 bytes, not more or less.

Comment: @owlstead, I changed the sample digest.

Comment: @falsetru thanks, cannot vote up anymore though, already at +1 :)

Comment: Ah. I though you were the asker.